# Magento 2 and Varnish 5

Tags: magento2, varnish

According to Magento DevDocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html,

> Magento 2 supports Varnish versions 3.0.5 or later or any Varnish 4.x
>   version.

Is there anyone who has tried Varnish 5 with Magento 2?

Comment: v5 do NOT exist in repository anymore now

Comment: Did you successfully got varnish 5 & magento2 working?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run into any issues. There aren't so many dramatic changes in Varnish Configuration Language between Varnish 4 & 5, so I suspect Magento's generated VCL will work out of the box with Varnish 5.

Answer (score 0):

Mine seems to work as well as with Varnish 4. I followed the guides starting here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-install.html

Magento has a configuration export for Varnish 5  (since versions 2.2.x) to download also now so they seem to be fine with Varnish 5 as stated in docs.

The VCL provided by magento does seem to just be for version 4 as the file states:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 5
vcl 4.0;
```

> **My Current issues with varnish were/are:**

1. The Menu dissapearing which was fixed by a simple google although this is a bit of a workaround:

   [Varnish top navigation menu gone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112310/varnish-top-navigation-menu-gone)
2. Larger Categories show error:

   ```
   Error 503 Backend fetch failed
   ```

   This can be fixed with help from here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html although currently this is not working for me.

Neither which are due to Varnish 5 however thought i would mention. All other testing seems to be mostly ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento 2.2 Varnish 5 is officially supported (see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html )

But as stated before, since there are no Major changed you will probably be find using Magento 2.0 or Magento 2.1. (You still might want to consider upgrading Magento 2.0 as it will not receive any more bug fixes)