# How can we remove an attribute from the xml block in layout file in magento2?

Tags: magento2, navigation, topmenu, megamenu

I need to remove the **ttl attribute** value from **catalog.topnav** block in `default.xml` file.
I have overrided the file in custom path as follows:

> Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
   <attribute name="ttl" value="" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Original block is as follows:

```
 <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-">
```

Comment: You can try unset

Answer (score 2):

I have overrided the file in custom path as follows:

> Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="store.menu">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.without.ttl" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

and override also the

> Magento_Theme/layout/print.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav.without.ttl" remove="true"/>
```

maybe it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

late but it works for me

```
   <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
        <action method="unsetData">
            <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">ttl</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```